# parameter has incomplete type error c programming

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have the following code and I am getting an error that says the parameter `map` has an incomplete type. The variable `strings` is an `smap` declared as an extern in one of the header files included where the following code resides.

How can I fix this, or what does the error mean, or  what are common causes for this error?

```
void print_strings(smap map);

void emit_strings(AST *ast) {
/* TODO: Implement me. */
    printf(".data\n");
    print_strings(strings);
}

void print_strings(smap map){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < map -> num_buckets; i += 1) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < map -> buckets[i].num_pairs; j+=1) {
            printf("str%d:  .asciiz  %c\n",label_count,map ->buckets[i].pairs[j].key);
            label_count ++;
        }
    }

    label_count = 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to also include the file where `smap` is defined.

Comment: Incomplete type means there's a declaration like `struct smap;` in the header file. If your code isn't linked against a source file that defines this struct, it's an incomplete type.

Comment: @Austin you should put that as an answer. Likely he thought the extern was the definition.

Comment: I was waiting for more info from OP, but I guess I can share what I know for now.

Answer (score 3):

I previously posted an incorrect answer, but user @mafso graciously steered me back in the right direction.

The problem I overlooked before is that your `print_strings` function attempts to directly access member variables of the `smap` type. Since this is an incomplete type (i.e. it is defined in a separate source file), you cannot do this. You need to work with whatever functions are declared in the header in order to access the `buckets` and their internal values.

A typical header might look like this:

```
#ifndef SMAP_H
#define SMAP_H

#include "bucket.h"
#include <stdlib>

typedef struct string_map *smap;

smap smap_create(size_t num_buckets);
bucket *smap_get_buckets(smap map):

void *smap_add_bucket(smap map, bucket b);

#endif
```

In this example, instead of using `map->buckets` to access the `buckets` member, you would call the getter: `smap_get_buckets(map)`.

The truth is, this is all speculation, because you still haven't provided any hints about the files that declare and define `smap`.